# Change Primary Front-End MariaDB ColumnStore Module

Tags: mariadb, columnstore

In my Mariadb Columnstore I have two Front-End MariaDB ColumnStore Module.
Now in de systemstatus I see that the Primary Front-End MariaDB ColumnStore Module is set on um2.

Is it possible to change this to um1?
If so how can I do this?

Arjan Kroon

Answer (score 0):

According to e.g. [columnstore-1.1.2 code](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-columnstore-engine/blob/columnstore-1.1.2/oamapps/mcsadmin/mcsadmin.cpp#L6884):

```
cout << endl << "This command stops the processing of applications on the Primary User Module, which is where DDL/DML are performed";
if (confirmPrompt("If there is another module that can be changed to a new Primary User Module, this will be done"))
```

the command:

```
mcsadmin alterSystem-disableModule um2
```

should change the Primary Front-End module to um1.